how to label an amodal dataset like COCOA?
We often use the COCO dataset for instance segmentation via LabelMe, and recently amodal instance segmentation has become popular since it can be aware of occluded objects. There are some public amodal datasets such as COCOA and KINS, but how to label them is not clear for me. And I'm going to label my own amodal dataset, how should I do this?I try to lable them by LabelMe,but LableMe has no parameters such as occlude_rate,visible_mask,invisible_mask,
here is COCOA Dataset json flie
enter image description here
here is COCO dataset json flie
enter image description here
I have my dataset for COCO format,how to label them to amodal dataset like COCOA and KINS?

[mre] required: post your text/json data as text, not as screenshots.
